# How to view stdout of a running python started by crontab

Tags: python, cron

I have a running python program (on Amazon linux server). This program was started by crontab.

How can I view its content stdout without stopping it?

Answer (score 3):

You could just read the proc filesystem :

```
tail -f /proc/28897/fd/1
```

**28897** is the process id.

You can get the process id using `ps`

For instance : `ps aux | grep myScript.py`

Comment: Have you given the right process id ?
Which command are you talking about ?

Comment: command "tail -f /proc/<my process id>/fd/1". I use "print" in my python program

Comment: this should definitively work that's weird, maybe try /fd/2

Comment: Are you sure your program is in a state where it should be outputting messages? `tail`ing on a file descriptor won't give you any old messages, it will only print new ones. 
Consider either writing to a file via https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=write#file.write, or use shell redirection via `./foo.py >> bar.txt` and then run `tail -f bar.txt` from a terminal

Comment: redirect to a file works for me. Thanks Oliver Baumann and Loic

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Loïc's answer:

The "1" at the end of `tail -f /proc/28897/fd/1` denotes the stream you want to look into. 0 is STDIN, 1 is STDOUT, 2 is STDERR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)

Adding this as it can be quite cryptic to understand the black magic behind FDs, and as I don't have enough rep to comment ;-)